# Bounding box values not supports fraction in Jsx graph

Tags: jsxgraph

Here i attached fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/anandi2i/9c16urun/3/

Not able to draw my graph with start value as 2.5 and end value as 12.5

Is jsxGraph API supports the fraction value? i don't know...

People who know something related to this....please help me to overcome

```
//Board initialization
    brdyy = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard("jxgbox", {
    axis: false,
    borders: false,
    boundingbox: [2.5, -5, 12.5, 5],
    arc: {
        firstArrow: true,
        lastArrow: true,
        fillColor: 'none',
        highlightFillColor: 'none',
        strokeColor: '#0000ff',
        useDirection: false
    },
    showNavigation: false,
    showCopyright: false,
    keepaspectratio: false,
    grid: false
});
//Axis creation
xaxis = brdyy.create('axis', [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0]
], {
    firstArrow: true,
    lastArrow: true,
    ticks: {
        insertTicks: false,
        drawZero: true,
        majorHeight: 10,
        minorHeight: 5,
        minorTicks: 5,
        tickEndings: [2, 2],
        ticksDistance: 1,
        strokeColor: '#121212',
        label: {
            offset: [-2, -20]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you cannot do? I see a scale starting at 2.5 and ending at 12.5 in jsfiddle.

Comment: I need a graph with starting value as 2.5 and end at some fraction value.Here i couldn't able to find out attributes for that...Actually "Scale" is used for tick distance management..My question is how to draw the graph with the exact bounding options

Answer (score 0):

To show the labels for 2.5 and 12.5 you have to use the `ticksDistance` and set it to `0.5`. Also change the bounding box to: `boundingbox: [2, -5, 13, 5]` so they are in the visible area.

[image: jsxgraph axis ticks]

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yprZaL